# How can I find the current position of the stack without a stack pointer in micro controller programming?

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, 8051, keil

How can I find stack position without using stack pointer you were given with upper bound of stack and depth of stack using embedded C or assembly language for 8051. Can anybody please help me finding the answer.

Comment: So you get one end of the stack, and the size,and want to find the other end?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Stack grows downwards right. Thats why its said 'depth' the starting is called upperbound (07H). So without noting the SP, I have to tell where the stack position is now(after some operation).
That is, size is given, start point is given. Without using the stack pointer how to tell where is the current stack position is.

Comment: is the depth the max depth, or the current depth? because if it is the current depth the SP is simply the (sum|difference) of the starting address and the current depth. Say you start from 0x07ff growing down, and current size is 0xf, then SP is at 0x07f0 (or 0x07ef if SP points to the first free location)

Comment: It's a stupid question, only valid _iff_ the architecture and compiler is specified.

Comment: @pipe, agreed. I guess that if it's a job interview question, they are just looking to see how you would start solving the problem, what kind of thought processes are going on in your head, do you get stuck, do you ask for help, do you give quick but incorrect answer, or take forever before admitting that you can't do it yourself, things like that. They might also be assessing your general knowledge about microcontrollers, or the 8051 architecture, or of compilers and stack layouts in general...

Comment: @pipe: You are right for C, but in 8051 assembler it's certainly possible if you know which memory area is "reserved" for the stack. Even so I agree with PkP that interview questions are rarely about finding out whether you know *"specific thing X"* but rather about seeing your approach to problem solving in general.

Comment: The sensible thing to do would be to look up the programming manual and find the address of the stack pointer 0x81 and access it directly. The stack in the 8051 grows **upwards** in any case. Maybe they wanted you to think about that possibility and how to make such a construct more portable.

Answer (score 7):

As noted in the comments, not using the stack pointer when there is one is really silly and nobody would ever do it in real life. Just like writing a FizzBuzz program.

Yes, you do need knowledge of processor architectures, but that's not the main thing the interviewers want to know. They could find out that by just asking you knowledge questions.

What the question is *really* about is your approach to problem solving: Do you just say that you don't know? Do you just sit there silently, apparently doing nothing, before announcing that you don't know? Do you start to cry? Do you try to talk (with the interviewers or with yourself) about the problem in order to discuss and/or dismiss the different ways to approach the problem? Do you start to sketch your options on paper or draw a mind-map? These are the things which the interviewers will be looking at, and some of them make a better impression than others.

---

So here's the uninteresting part of the answer, the algorithm:

1. Push a known value on the stack, say `0x77`.
2. Scan the whole stack space for this value (you know start and maximum size of the stack).
3. Once you find `0x77` somwhere, execute a `POP` instruction and push `0x88`.
4. Check that memory address again. If it changed to `0x88`, that's the top of your stack. Go to 6.
5. If it didn't change, continue scanning and repeat steps 3-5 until you reach the end of the stack or find a changing value.
6. Execute a `POP` to clean up after yourself.

*Note:* If you don't know the location and size of the stack, you could also scan the whole address space, which likely isn't that big in a micro controller. You just need to be careful that your implementation uses no RAM, lest it places the searched value somewhere outside of the stack and confuses itself.

Comment: +1 ,it looks like , you are the one how made the question for the interview :))

Comment: +1, you've done better than me. :)

Comment: How do you push a value onto the stack without having the stack pointer?

Comment: Oh I see there is a specific push instruction for the 8051

Comment: This is likely why _"you were given with upper bound of stack and depth of stack"_ was mentioned.

Comment: @pipe: Even if those were not given you could still scan the whole address space, which typically isn't that big in micro controllers. :)

Comment: @ElectronS: Thanks, but that certainly wasn't me. :)

Comment: It is silly to assume that you have access to a push instruction but not a store stack pointer instruction. Why these kind of artificial tasks is of mild interest in the real world...

Comment: @Lundin: Of course it is silly not to use a specific feature of your processor in general. But that's not the point of interview questions. See the comments below the question for details. (besides, if you leave out *all* stack-related instructions, then you don't have a stack, so forbidding `PUSH` and `POP` would be even less sensible).

Comment: I managed to try out what you suggested.
Please correct me if you find anything stupid.

`ORG 00H
;simply incr. stack pointer(substitute for some random operations)
push 85h
push 65h
 ;*********************************
 
 ; a value, say #77h is put into stack
MOV 33H,#77H
PUSH 33H
;*************************************

; a value 88h is stored in a location 44h
MOV 44H, #88H
MOV R0, #07H; r0 made to position at start of stack(suppose given upperbound is 07h)

J:
INC R0
CJNE @R0, #77H, J ; searching for the value 77h in the stack
POP 45H
PUSH 44H


END`

Comment: @HarikrishnanVNair Sorry, I don't know any 8051 assembler, which is why I wrote the algorithm in text form instead of source code. So I can't really answer your question. Maybe you could post it as a separate question here or on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a pure programming question, but alas...

You can find the location of the stack by placing a variable on the stack, then take the address of the variable:

```
function stack_check()
{
   int i;

   int *p = &i;
   printf("End of stack is %p\n", p);
}
```

Nicked from [arduino.stackexchange.com](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/355/how-much-can-i-recurse-how-much-can-i-recurse-how-much-caqfsdrfw)

Comment: There is no guarantee that the variable "i" will be on the stack.  You can not infer machine-dependent details like this from standard C.  It *probably* works that way on machines with stacks, like the 8051, but to give this as a unqualified answer is just wrong.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Surely compilers have large leeway in how to compile this. But the combination of a variable and taking the address of a variable prohibits it from using registers fo `i`, for example.

Comment: That's a good point about the taking the address of the variable, it must be placed in RAM. But whether it's in the stack, that's another matter. With SDCC compiler for 8051 with no memory allocation directives, it's placed in a static address. SDCC uses a call tree allocation to overlay local variables in static addresses by default and code void * GetStack() {int i; return &i;} compiles into _GetStack: mov dptr,#_GetStack_i_1_1; mov b,#0x00; ret. I think that it's compiler and memory model dependent and asm is the only way to go.

Comment: *"Maybe, maybe not."*  Exactly.  That's the point.  You can't rely on it.  That's why this is not a good answer, at least not without a lot more constraints and warnings.

Comment: By taking the address of a variable, you ensure that it is not stored in a register. This behavior is only guaranteed "between the lines" by the C standard though. If you assume that all such variables always get `register` storage class, then the code will work. But the C standard actually does not enforce this - it only enforces that `register` variables cannot have their address taken.

Comment: Also, the address of `i` is not the stack pointer, since when it is given a location on the stack, the SP has gone past it. Assuming down-counting stack, you'd have to take `(uint8_t*)i - sizeof(i)` to get the actual stack pointer.

Comment: @JvO on an "ordinary" processor perhaps taking the address of a value forces it to memory and hopefully the stack, but the CPU registers of the subject 8051 are accessible at memory addresses!

Answer (score -1):

[Edit] This not the correct answer, as Fritz's answer is clearly what was looked for :) But I'll let this answer remain here for the discussion of calling conventions. Especially the variadic functions (those with a variable number of arguments) are interesting in this respect.

---

This is in addition to JvO's answer, that suggests to get the stack pointer by getting the address of a stack allocated variable. I've also used this technique. But it was noted by Olin that the variable might not be allocated from the stack, which is also true. This lead me to think about the following approach:

```
void *GetStack(int *i, ...) {
    return &i;
}
```

The variable arguments passing guarantees, that the first parameter must be placed in a RAM address, since the rest of the arguments are guaranteed to follow it in memory (the first argument must be passable to a va_start macro), and as such there's a good chance that it is in the stack. So while it doesn't pinpoint the exact address of the top of stack, it could be quite close and should be worth a try if JvO's method doesn't work.

PS. if you know that the first argement must or must not be a pointer, please go ahead and edit the answer.

---

[Edit] I just realized that the question was specific to 8051, so I did a quick test on SDCC compiler. SDCC uses a call tree allocation to overlay local variables in static addresses by default and the code

```
void * GetStack() {
  int i; 
  return &i;
}
```

compiles into

```
_GetStack: 
  mov dptr,#_GetStack_i_1_1
  mov b,#0x00
  ret
```

Meaning that i is not in the stack, it's a static address decided by the compiler. I think that it's so compiler and memory model dependent that asm is the only real way to go.

---

My first suggested function

```
void *GetStack2(int *i, ...) {
    return &i;
}
```

seems to do a bit better, it compiles into:

```
GetStack2:
        push    _bp
        mov     _bp,sp
        mov     a,_bp
        add     a,#0xfb
        mov     r2,a
        mov     r3,#0x00
        mov     r4,#0x0
        mov     dpl,r2
        mov     dph,r3
        mov     b,r4
        mov     sp,_bp
        pop     _bp
        ret
```

which at least references SP. With asm the code could be made much cleaner, I suppose.

Comment: Couldn't the function's parameters be stored in registers?

Comment: @m.Alin, no, because the variable arguments list needs a pointer go get the address of the first argument and registers don't have addresses...

Comment: @PkP: But according to the OP, referencing SP is forbidden.

Comment: @Fritz, oops, missed that. Hmm.. this is getting interesting. Could he use malloca() to get some memory? That for sure allocates from the stack.

Comment: "that the first parameter must be placed in a RAM address, since the rest of the arguments are guaranteed to follow it in memory" This is complete nonsense. All of this depends on _calling convention_ and is utterly system-specific. Many microcontrollers use a calling convention which is a mix of registers and stack. If you don't even know the calling convention for the specific compiler, your example is just a shot in the dark. And there are absolutely no guarantees of the order of allocation of stack parameters either.

Comment: @PkP on the 8051 CPU registers *do* have memory addresses.  But the whole premise of using the functional call as a forcer is mistaken unless one has more specific details of the compiler's behavior than provided.

Comment: @Lundin, utter nonsense? Really? I thought that varargs were always passed like this. Even on the ARM, which passes parameters in registers as per the ARM ABI, the parameters are *copied* to the stack in the case of variadic functions so that they can be accessed by the va_arg macro. I'd be genuinely interested if you could point to me a compiler (and an example stdarg.h file, perhaps) of an architecture or a calling convention that *doesn't* work like this, as I'm sort of a C language fan and fanatic... :) Cheers, best regards!

Comment: @ChrisStratton, those memory addresses are in a different memory space than the stack, they are in the direct 8-bit space (upper halve to be exact) while the stack is in the indirect 8-bit space, which exists in parallel with the upper halve in 8052 and in any case, certainly 8051 registers do *not* have an address that could be passed as a parameter to the va_start macro. va_start requires a parameter that is the beginning of a list in memory. Well, I guess that *technically* another kind of implementation might be possible within stdargs spec - I would be interested to know if there is one!